# TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined facing

Tags: reactjs, e-commerce, mern

```
import React from 'react'
import Product from '../product'
import {Row,Col,ListGroup,Button,Image}from 'react-bootstrap'
const ProductDetails = ({match}) => {
    const product=Product.find((p)=>p._id === match.params.id)
    return (
        <div>
       <Row>
           <Col md={6} >
        <Image src={product.image} alt={product.name} fluid />
           </Col>
           
       </Row> 

       
        </div>
    )
}

export default ProductDetails
```

I am creating a project of simple e-commerce site and importing product list  from the product.js file  and  I want to show a single product page  but facing this error like TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined
.
So help me to solve the issues.

product.js

```
const products=[
    {
        _id:'1',
        name:'product 1',
        images: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random'   ,
        description:' Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. ',
        price: 50,
        countInStock:10,
        rating:4.5,
        numReviews:12,
    },
    {
        _id:'2',
        name:'product 2',
        images: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random'   ,
        description:'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  ',
        price:258,
        countInStock:7,
        rating:3.5,
        numReviews:25,
    },
    {
        _id:'3',
        name:'product 3',
        images: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random'   ,
        description:'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  ',
        price:500,
        countInStock:10,
        rating:4.5,
        numReviews:12,
    },
    {
        _id:'4',
        name:'product 4',
        images: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random'   ,
        description:' Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. ',
        price:1000,
        countInStock:8,
        rating:2.5,
        numReviews:9,
    },
    
       
]
export default products
```

And this how I am calling ProductDetails components in App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import{Route,BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom"
import './App.css';
//import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'

import ProductDetails from './screens/ProductDetails' 
const  App=() =>{
  return (
   <>
    
    <Route path="/product/:id" >
      <ProductDetails/>
        </Route>
    
       </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Howdy, can you show us how are you calling the `ProductDetails ` component ?

Comment: @rigojr Please checkout, I already updated the way I am calling  ProductDetails

Comment: Nice! Looks like the `ProductDetails` is not getting any `props` related to `match ` on `const ProductDetails = ({match})`. How are you passing the `match` info ?